# VLOOKUP return duplicate matches return first alphabetic value

Tags: excel, indexing, google-sheets, vlookup, gs-vlookup

I am trying to lookup for a value matches multiple locations. Want to bring the first alphabetic match bu VLOOKUP brings the Last alphabetic match. Here is the table.

```
7884    A11
7884    A12
7875    A11
```

Look up Value 7884 and want to return A11, VLOOKUP returns A12.

I am trying to do this in googlesheets. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The vlookup will only work if column B is sorted alphabetically.  Luckily Google Sheets has a few tricks up it's sleeve.  You can use the Query function to sort the results and limit them to 1.

```
=query(A1:B3,"SELECT B where A = 7884 order by B ASC limit 1")
```

Dynamic lookup value

```
=query(A1:B3,"SELECT B where A = "& D1 &" order by B ASC limit 1")
```

Comment: This works like a charm, the perfect formula I was looking for.

Comment: That's great!  You can mark it as the accepted answer so other peaple can see the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This will return A11:

```
=vlookup(7884,A2:B4,2,false)
```

Comment: Not all the times actually. My case has a large table array, need to filter out the data.

Comment: Vlookup with false works on your example. Give an example of what does not work.